# Limitar largo de un texto

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Si tengo un `div`

```
#div {width:300px;height:200px;overflow-y:scroll}
```

El usuario le agregara un texto mediante `prompt`, que se añadirá como un elemento de párrafo con:

```
element.createElement("P")
```

Cómo puedo limitar a que si el usuario ingresa un texto de más de `300px` de largo, este texto crezca hacia abajo *(por algo el overflow-y)* , así como un chat.

Comment: si lo partes por el length?

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar una de estas dos propiedades CSS:

- [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) (con el valor `break-all`): indica si el navegador debe incluir saltos de línea allí donde la palabra rebasa el tamaño del contenedor.
- [`overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) (con el valor `break-word`): indica si el navegador debe incluir saltos de línea dentro de una palabra si va a rebasar el tamaño del contenedor.

Como puedes ver, los dos son bastante parecidos. La diferencia principal es que `overflow-wrap` sólo creará el salto de línea dentro de una palabra si la palabra completa no entra en una línea (si no, el salto lo pondrá en el espacio con la palabra anterior), lo que hace que las frases sean más "naturales" al no romperse las palabras a no ser que sea estrictamente necesario.

En cambio `break-word` romperá la palabra cuando llegue al final de la línea, sin importar si hubiera entrado entera en la siguiente línea (dando un efecto de alineación justificada, pero rompiendo las palabras de forma menos natural).

Un problema es que no está soportado por el navegador Edge (ninguna de las dos, ni `overflow-wrap` ni `word-break`) y que muchos navegadores móviles no soportan bien `word-break` (visitar enlaces para ver tablas de soporte).

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var texto = prompt("Escribe algo");
  var p = document.createElement("P");
  var t = document.createTextNode(texto);
  p.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("div").appendChild(p);
});
```

```css
#div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border:1px solid gray; /* para visualizar mejor la caja */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<button>Agrega texto</button>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no me equivoco, todo párrafo tiene la propiedad `white-space:` con el atributo `normal` por defecto así que no habría problema, pues así se crea un salto cuando llega al máximo width.

Por otro lado el atributo `nowrap` hace que se quede todo como está, sin saltos de línea. De cualquier forma presento dos soluciones:

La primera es `parrafo1()` que se basa en `white-space: normal`

La segunda es `parrafo2()` que se basa en colocar un salto de línea cada 40 caracteres (son los que en promedio pude notar que ocupan los 300px).

```js
function main(){
 var texto = prompt("Ingresa el texto: ");
 if (!texto)
  texto = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi non quis exercitationem culpa nesciunt nihil aut nostrum explicabo reprehenderit optio amet ab temporibus asperiores quasi cupiditate. Voluptatum ducimus voluptates voluptas?";
 return texto;
}
function parrafo1(){
 var texto = main();
 var p = document.createElement("p");
 p.textContent = texto;
 document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].appendChild(p);
}
function parrafo2(){
 var texto = main(), auxiliar = [];
 for (var i = 40; i < texto.length; i+=40){
  auxiliar.push(texto.substring(i-40, i));
  auxiliar.push("<br />");
 }
 auxiliar = auxiliar.join("");
 document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = auxiliar; 
}
```

```css
 div{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
 }
 /*div p{
  white-space: nowrap;
 }*/
```

```html
<div></div>
<button onclick="parrafo1()">Click</button>
```

En el **CSS** quita el comentario para apreciar la diferencia en cuanto a los saltos de línea. También cambia en el botón `parrafo1()` por `parrafo2()` para probar un método u otro.

Comment: Ambos métodos fallan para la cadena `01234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyz1234567890`

Comment: Cierto @Alvaro, creo que tu respuesta es la más óptima pues funciona y es sólo css, agradezco la observación y una pregunta por qué sucede eso?? me quedé con la intriga